# How to plot the solution to a second order differential equation in maple

Tags: plot, differential-equations, maple

My code is attached in the pictures. How can I plot the solution y(x) as a function of x? The solution to this BVP y(x) is given by the command dsolve({de, ics})
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTauU.png)

with(DEtools);

```
      w := 20
      t := 5
      L := 200
      Base_TD := 0
      End_TD := 100
      x0 := 100
      K := 350*10^(-6)
      h := 850*10^(-12)
      de := diff(y(x), x, x) = 2*h*(w + t)*y(x)/(K*w*t) - (x - x0)^2
      dsolve(de)
      ics := y(0) = Base_TD, D(y)(100) = -h*End_TD/K
      dsolve({de, ics})
```

Comment: Nobody should have to retype all your code, and posting merely an image of code is inconsiderate. You should convert the code to 1D plaintext notation and edit that into your Question (as quoted text).

Comment: @acer I've added more info, hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this exactly, or numerically.

The plot of those agree with each other quite well.

```
restart;
w := 20: t := 5: L := 200:
Base_TD := 0: End_TD := 100: x0 := 100:
K := 350*10^(-6): h := 850*10^(-12):

de := diff(y(x), x, x)
      = 2*h*(w + t)*y(x)/(K*w*t)
        - (x - x0)^2:

ics := y(0) = Base_TD,
       D(y)(100) = -h*End_TD/K:
```

Solved exactly, and then plot constructed,

```
exactsol := dsolve({de, ics}):

PE := plot(rhs(exactsol), x=0..100):
```

Solved numerically (ie. generating a procedure, which solves numerically at points in time on demand), and then plot constructed,

```
numericsol := dsolve({de, ics}, numeric):

PN := plots:-odeplot(numericsol,[x,y(x)],
                     x=0..100,
                     thickness=5,color=green):
```

Showing both together, for comparison,

```
plots:-display(PN,PE);
```

[image]

Checking the second boundary condition,

```
evalf(ics);
numericsol(100);
plots:-odeplot(numericsol,[x,diff(y(x),x)],
               x=90 .. 100,
               thickness=5,color=green);
```

Comment: If it answers you question fully then you might consider "accepting" it (green tick mark).